# huggingface-transformers: Train BERT and evaluate it using different attentions

Tags: transformer-model, huggingface-transformers

This is a clarification question. I am trying to train [BERT provided by huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) using standard attention, and evaluate using a different attention definition.

The operation I was thinking about was change `bert-base-uncased` to the path of my trained model(using standard attention) in the following command, and run `--do_eval` under the installation of my customized attention version.

```
export GLUE_DIR=/path/to/glue
export TASK_NAME=MRPC

python ./examples/run_glue.py \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased \
    --task_name $TASK_NAME \
    --do_eval \
    --data_dir $GLUE_DIR/$TASK_NAME \
    --max_seq_length 128 \
    --per_gpu_eval_batch_size=8   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size=8   \
    --learning_rate 2e-5 \
    --num_train_epochs 3.0 \
    --output_dir /tmp/$TASK_NAME/
```

However, I was getting unexpected results. So I want to make sure that I was using the right command. Could anyone confirm with me or correct me?

Edited: The version was 2.8.0.

Comment: Please post the error message and add the version of transformersyou are using.

Comment: I do not have an error message, it was outputting results. I edited and added the version. @cronoik

Comment: What do you mean with 'under the installation of my custom attention'? What did you do? Did you replace the corrosponding transformers methods?

Comment: Yes. I changed the implementation of BertSelfAttention. Sorry for the confusion. @cronoik

Comment: Yes that should work actually. The results should be different with the original BertSelfAttention. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes. I got exactly the same results on one dataset, and another nearly the same(only different in loss) results on another dataset, both in GLUE benchmark. Thanks for confirming with this! I will further check the exact attention value then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Confirmed by @cronoik, this is the correct operation.